# Receipt not CC-ed for offline donations

Tags: civicontribute, receipts

Why is a receipt not sent to the email addresses set in the Contribution Page for an offline receipt. For instance, online donations to the "Shoe" contribution page are all cc-ed to "bookkeeping". But when an offline donation is processed and the "Shoe" contribution campaign is chosen, no cc happens. Is this because it doesn't run through these page settings when sending the email?

Based on Ken West's comment here [Why is offline contribution sending an online receipt?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4898/why-is-offline-contribution-sending-an-online-receipt) I'm guessing that's the case??

> "CRM_Contribute_BAO_ContributionPage::sendMail(). So there's an
>   assumption that a Contribution Page is involved."

Is there not a way to simply set a CC, even if to say if no contribution page is involved, default the CC to bookkeeping? Even if it can't pick up the info on a page by page basis a default email is a better solution than no email.

Comment: If you mark an off-line contribution as related to an Online Contribution page (under Additional Details), does that invoke the settings of that contribution page (and thus the CC/BCC email)?

Comment: Hmm... Just tested that.  Doesn't seem to trigger the emails.  I wonder what benefit associating the contribution to the Online Contribution page provides.

Comment: That was my hope too but as you see it doesn't work, I don't know enough about civi to understand why it skips the cc.

Answer (score 1):

Coming from a different angle, perhaps you could use [CiviRules](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules) (along with the added extension [Email API](https://civicrm.org/extensions/e-mail-api) to enable CiviRules to send emails) so that any time a contribution is added, you could send an email to your bookkeeping address.  (And thus you wouldn't need the CC or BCC for the contribution pages).

Out of the box, you can set conditions for different financial types.  Another option: if you didn't want to go to use CiviRules for *every* contribution, just the off line ones, you could create a custom field for contributions indicating off line, and then use a CiviRules condition of Field Comparison for your new custom field, so emails get sent via CiviRules only when the back office is filling it out.

Comment: This is a good thought, I mean I'm happy to be poking around CiviRules, I can see some great uses of it. But in this case merely notifying the 'bookkeeper' is not enough, I need an actual copy of the receipt sent to the donor.

Comment: When you enter an off line contribution for a contact who has an email in the system already, a checkbox should appear that offers to send a receipt to the donor... Do you not have that?  See this example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f212hp8n8gjkpti/send%20receipt%20off%20line%20contrib.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Yes, I have that and the donor gets a receipt. But I'd like a cc of that receipt.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Thanks for clarifying.  Could you copy and paste the receipt template (from Administer>Communications>Message Templates) into the email that CiviRules sends to bookkeeper?  (I don't know the answer to that... I'm not sure if emails sent by CiviRules accepts tokens.)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it, but I don't see an option in CiviRules to simply send an email. I can add an activity to a contact but there's no outright 'send an email' option. (Civi 4.6.4, WP4.4.2, Civi Rules 1.2)

Comment: Do you have the email API extension installed as well? (See answer for the link)

Comment: I did not have it installed - doh. I'd like to say I got further in testing to see if I could just use the same language from the default receipt in the cc-ed version but CiviRules is messing with some event items (I'm still in 4.6) so I have to disable for now :(